# Using xxcopy to flatten a directory without adding the subdirectory name?

Tags: windows, xxcopy

I'm trying to flatten an existing directory with subdirectories into another directory using xxcopy.

My command currently looks like:

```
xxcopy .\VisitraxImages .\VisitraxImagesNew /s /sx
```

Unfortunately this command results in filenames that contain the former subfolder's name in them.

For example, if a file named `bob.joe.TR.2.13.13.pdf` in the source directory (`.\VisitraxImages`) was in a sub-directory called `the_directory`, when it copies over to the newly flattened directory (`.\VisitraxImagesNew`) it would be named `bob.joe.TR.2.13.13'the_directory.pdf` instead of `bob.joe.TR.2.13.13.pdf`

I would rather exclude the duplicate filename and be notified of duplicate filenames in the command output than outright change the filename all together.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sort of found a solution but not exactly...there's a way to copy the newest file with the name into the flattened directory if you take my command above and add the `/SGN` switch to it... http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy16.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sort of found a solution but not exactly...there's a way to copy the newest file with the name into the flattened directory if you take my command above and add the /SGN switch to it... Source: [xxcopy.com/xxcopy16.htm](http://xxcopy.com/xxcopy16.htm)

```
xxcopy .\VisitraxImages .\VisitraxImagesNew /s /sx / SGN
```